# Getting time periods from consecutive timestamps and activities per user

Tags: knime

```
uid activity    timestamp
123 Activity1   1370520169521
123 Activity1   1370520279532
123 Activity2   1370520319543
123 Activity2   1370520419554
123 Activity2   1370520569565
123 Activity1   1370520679576
123 Activity1   1370520779587
123 Activity1   1370520879598
123 Activity1   1370520979612
```

For each user, I want to create the beginning and end of a time period when an activity starts and when it ends.

```
uid activity    start               end
123 Activity1   1370520169521       1370520279532
123 Activity2   1370520319543       1370520569565
123 Activity1   1370520679576       1370520979612
```

How can I get these periods?